# Выборка по нескольким тегам в xpath

Tags: xpath

Например, так получаю все H2(работаю с HtmlAgilityPack)

```
doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//h2")
```

Можно как-то вытащить в одной коллекции H2 и H3, наподобие селекторов jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//h2 | //h3")
```

или так:

```
doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//*[self::h2 or self::h3]")
```